# Is there an alternative to requiring common node modules besides globals?

Tags: node.js

Getting tired of typing

```
const async = require('async');
const _ = require('lodash');
```

at the head of almost every JS file.

One could use globals, good for ease of use, bad for unit tests.

Is there an alternative that I'm missing? If I can do a `require('common')` to load the utilities I want and use them in the current file, that would be best.

Comment: There really isn't an alternative.  Just get use to requiring in the common things you want in each module (it takes some getting used to, but eventually it just starts to feel natural).  Doing it this way makes modules independently testable and independently shareable without needing some shared infrastructure that they all depend on.  I personally wouldn't recommend `common.js` myself because it just obscures what you're actually loading and creates an unnecessary dependency all to save a little typing.

Comment: also, some tooling like VS Code will automatically include your `include` or `require` statements when you go to use a module, much like how tooling for C# automatically includes `using` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well then do that - create a *common.js* file and put all the stuff in there, then simply require whatever you need in a single statement using the destructuring assignment.

### Example

**common.js**

```
module.exports = {
    fs: require('fs'),
    http: require('http')
    //... what else you want
};
```

**main.js**

```
const { fs, http } = require('./common.js');
```

---

### Note

This was just an example to show you how to archive your desired behaviour. But I would not recommend you to use this as it *obscures what you're actually loading* and bring a unnecessary dependency just to save some statements.

Comment: This works, but it is not my favorite technique as it just creates an unnecessary dependency and obscures what you're actually loading just to save a small amount of typing.  IMO, fewest characters typed is not the higher goal here.

Comment: Agreed, I would never do this in production

Comment: I agree - wouldn't do that either, but is actually that what OP was asking for

Comment: Yea, nothing seems like a good practice. I guess I'll just keep typing.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, there's this amazing thing called keyboard snippets which completely saves one from typing those redundant characters over and over, without the need for compromising the integrity of the code.

VSCode

```
  "debug require": {
    "prefix": "rede",
    "body": [
      "const debug = require('debug')('$1');$0"
    ]
  },
  "lodash require": {
    "prefix": "relo",
    "body": [
      "const _ = require('lodash');$0"
    ]
  },
  "async require": {
    "prefix": "reas",
    "body": [
      "const async = require('async');$0"
    ]
  },
```